Issues with WebRTC Transceivers: Unexpected Creation of recvonly Transceiver
I am trying to establish a WebRTC connection between two peers using transceivers to manage audio streams. I have a scenario where I expect each peer to have a single transceiver with the sendrecv direction. However, when I run the following code, I observe that the remoteConnection ends up with two transceivers: one sendrecv transceiver with a mid of null and an additional recvonly transceiver.
Here’s the code I’m using:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>WebRTC with Transceivers on Both Peers</h2>
    <button onclick="startConnection()">Start Connection</button>

    <script>
      let localConnection;
      let remoteConnection;
      let localStream;
      let remoteStream;

      async function startConnection() {
        // Step 1: Get audio from user's microphone for the local peer
        localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });

        // Step 2: Create local and remote peer connections
        localConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();
        remoteConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

        // Step 3: Handle ICE candidates for both peers
        localConnection.onicecandidate = (e) => {
          if (e.candidate) remoteConnection.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
        };
        remoteConnection.onicecandidate = (e) => {
          if (e.candidate) localConnection.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
        };

        // Step 4: Create transceivers on both peers
        // Local peer adds audio transceiver with 'sendrecv' direction
        const localTransceiver = localConnection.addTransceiver('audio', {
          direction: 'sendrecv',
        });
        localTransceiver.sender.replaceTrack(localStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

        // Remote peer also adds a transceiver for symmetry
        const remoteTransceiver = remoteConnection.addTransceiver('audio', { direction: 'sendrecv' });
        
        remoteTransceiver.sender.replaceTrack(localStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);

        // Step 5: Handle remote stream received on the remote peer
        remoteStream = new MediaStream();
        remoteConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
          remoteStream.addTrack(event.track);
          console.log('Received remote audio track');
          // Attach remoteStream to an audio element to play the received audio
          const remoteAudio = document.createElement('audio');
          remoteAudio.srcObject = remoteStream;
          remoteAudio.autoplay = true;
          document.body.appendChild(remoteAudio);
        };
        
        const offerj = await remoteConnection.createOffer();
        await remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(offerj);

        // Step 6: Start the offer/answer negotiation process
        const offer = await localConnection.createOffer();
        await localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
        await remoteConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);

        const answer = await remoteConnection.createAnswer();
        await remoteConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
        await localConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
         
        console.log(localConnection.getTransceivers())
        console.log(remoteConnection.getTransceivers())

        console.log('WebRTC connection established with transceivers on both sides.');
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Observations:
After running the code, I expected to see one sendrecv transceiver on both localConnection and remoteConnection.
Instead, remoteConnection ends up with two transceivers:

One sendrecv transceiver with a mid that is null.
One recvonly transceiver that appears to be automatically created during the negotiation process.

Questions:

What causes the additional recvonly transceiver to be created in remoteConnection?
How can I ensure that there is only one sendrecv transceiver on both peers as intended?

Expected Behavior:
I expect both peers to have one sendrecv transceiver, allowing them to send and receive audio seamlessly.
Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

This is working as intended, addTransceiver explicitly creates a transceiver without matching in setRemoteDescription that is done by addTrack.
The receivers transceiver you created will only be usable in a second negotiation initiated by the remote side.
